# HowTo preserve page hierarchy with wp_list_pages()?

Tags: hierarchical, wp-list-pages

I have created a dynamic way of displaying "sub-menu-items" using the built-in function `wp_list_pages()`. However I'm stuck with the hierarchy of the pages displayed because of the `sort_column` doesn't seem to have any "sorting" that could preserve the hierarchy of the pages displayed.

Here's my code:

```
function get_top_parent_page_id() {
    global $post;
    $ancestors = $post->ancestors;     
    // Check if page is a child page (any level)
    if ($ancestors) {
        //  Grab the ID of top-level page from the tree
        return end($ancestors);
    } else {
        // Page is the top level, so use  it's own id
        return $post->ID;
    }  
}   
$parent_page = get_top_parent_page_id(); 
$descendants = get_pages(array('child_of' => $parent_page, 'hierarchical' => 1));
$incl = "";   
foreach ($descendants as $page) {
    if (($page->post_parent == $parent_page) ||
        ($page->post_parent == $post->post_parent) ||
        ($page->post_parent == $post->ID)) 
    {
        $incl .= $page->ID . ",";
        if ($post->post_parent != get_top_parent_page_id()):
            $incl .= $post->post_parent . ",";
        endif;
    }
}?>

<ul>
    <?php wp_list_pages(array("child_of" => $parent_page, "include" => $incl, "link_before" => "", "title_li" => "", "depth" => "0", "sort_column" => "ID"));?>
</ul>
```

How should I modify my code to display all the pages needed with the page hierarchy intact?

What I need to achieve -

```
1.Top Level parent - ordering 1
1.1 Top level child - ordering 1
1.1.1 Top level child's child - ordering 1
1.1.2 Top level child's child - ordering 2
1.2 Top-level child - ordering 2
1.3 Top-level child - ordering 3
2.Top Level parent - ordering 2
3.Top Level parent - ordering 3
```

But what my code does at the moment with sort_column set to menu_order or post_title
on the childs of the parent items. For example, if I have pages nested like this

```
1.Top Level parent - ordering 1
1.1 Top level child - ordering 1
1.1.1 Top level child's child - ordering 1
1.1.2 Top level child's child - ordering 2
1.2 Top-level child - ordering 2
2.Top Level parent - ordering 2
1.3 Top-level child - ordering 3
3.Top Level parent - ordering 3
```

It basically works like this, but if the user wants to change the ordering of 1. Top level parent to appear second from the top, he has to manually set all the children to have the same ordering number.

Comment: I don't understand how this should benefit me. As I need to display all the child pages of corresponding parent pages. What I need is that the sort_column to only sort pages that are on the same level. Currently if I set sort_column into menu_order then it sorts all the pages as they're on the same level, regardless of the hierarchy of pages.

Comment: The default for the `'sort_column'` parameter of `wp_list_pages` is `'menu_order, post_title'`. This means that the pages will be listed in exactly the same way as they are in the admin area.

Comment: @kelk Sorry, I read it incorrectly. I read it "How to prevent..." My bad.

Comment: @DavidGard Thank you for your answer. However for some reason after setting the 'sort_column' parameter of wp_list_pages to 'menu_order, post_title' It lists the children above the parent menu items. (all the pages order number is currently set to 0, to preserve the hierarchy - however the client wants to change the ordering of the displayed pages)

The problem is that the current state of the code makes Wordpress ordering treat all the fetched pages as if they were on the same level. What I need to achive is that the wordpress ordering should treat the ordering only on parent items and then